# async-local-storage in nest.js tests

Tags: javascript, local-storage, mocha.js, nestjs

I've implemented async-local storage in nest.js from async hooks, but when I come to my mocha tests, I need to send an instance of it as a mock and I don't know what's the best way to do that.

I've tried two things:
First, to call from my beforeEach function in tests to call my getCtx() which calls the global store and it looks like this:

```
export function getCtx() {
  const requestContext = getGlobalStore();
  return requestContext.ctx;
}
```

Second, to change the function to get a parameter and send my context inside like this:

```
export function getGlobalStore(
  store: AsyncLocalStorage<ICtx> = globalStore,
): ICtx {
  const context = store.getStore();
  return context!;
}
```

and then in the test :

```
const store = new  AsyncLocalStorage<CtxMock>();
const context = getGlobalStore(store);
```

In both ways I get the error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ctx')"